How to get really used listener port inside Handler
Assume this code
handler := http.HandleFunc("/usedport", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte(strings.Split(r.RemoteAddr,":")[1]))
    })
l, err = net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")

All work well. We call to http://127.0.0.1:8080/usedport and get 8080 in answer
But... if port remaped at docker level for example
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/mybin:/mybin -p 8081:8080 ubuntu /mybin

We still listening on 8080, but calls are looks like
http://127.0.0.1:8081/usedport and anser is 8081
But i want to know exactly what listener port was used for request, so i want still get 8080 in answer.
During investigation it looks like i can access *http.Server from http.Request - r.Context().Value(http.ServerContextKey).(*http.Server)
But listeners info is private.
The only workaround is always to synchronize exposed and mapped ports, something like this:
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/mybin:/mybin -p 8081:8081 ubuntu /mybin --port 8081

But it's not look weel. Is where canonical or at least legal way to access information about port that was used to get request.

The listener port of the server is 8080. What you ask for is not the listener port but what port the client has used to connect to. This information is likely lost, i.e. your server does not know about this and can thus not provide the information.
